# How to connect to docker mysql container on remote machine

Tags: mysql, docker, remote-access, ports

I have two machines. My machine with `IP1(Europe)`, and other machine with public `IP2(USA)`. On `IP2` I have mysql container running with volume `/var/lib/mysql` set to be replicated in some folder on the host machine `~/mysqldatabase`. Firewall rule for port `3306` is added. Also I have ssh connection to the machine. So I'm not sure where to start. Usually when there is not docker I add just

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

as configuration in mysql and I open the firewall port `3306` (or an other one that points to mysql) and the things work.
So probably I can install mysql-server package (the host is ubuntu16.04) outside of docker on the IP2 machine and to set it to point to the `~/mysqldatabase` folder, but is it really necessary to do that? 
Is there way to connect directly from `IP1` to `IP2:mysql_container:mysql_database`

I run the mysql docker container in two ways. One is with docker file. And the other one is with systemctl service.

Part of the docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - /home/username/mysqldatabase:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpass
        MYSQL_DATABASE: somedb
        MYSQL_USER: someuser
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: someuserpassword
```

mysql.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Run %p
Requires=docker.service
After=docker.service

[Service]
Restart=always
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker kill %p
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker rm -f %p
docker run --rm --name mysql -v /home/username/mysqldatabase:/var/lib/mysql -p 3306:3306 \
-e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpass -e MYSQL_DATABASE=somedb -e MYSQL_USER=someuser -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=someuserpassword \
mysql:5.7
ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker stop %p

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

To make the things more simple lets say that I use only the second approach.

I DON"T have :

- 1.mysql-client, mysql-server or mysql on the IP2 machine
- 2.and I haven't set anywhere to bind to 0.0.0.0 because I want to connnect directly to the mysql container. Probably I have to set it
  to bind to 0.0.0.0 inside this container.

Result for the firewall

```
sudo netstat -tunlp | grep 3306
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN      24717/docker-proxy
```

Comment: I am not still not clear as to what the question is here? There are two things `I have to set it to bind to 0.0.0.0 inside this container.` By default inside the container mysql bind is `0.0.0.0` only. Next when you use `-p 3306:3306` in docker that itself is a bind to `0.0.0.0` on the host machine. Which means the 3306 is exposed on the host a well. Now can you please clarify what exactly is the problem that you want to get resolved?

Comment: OK. I didn't know that part that by default in the container mysql is bind to 0.0.0.0 Thank you for that info. I don't have to try again then, because it didn't worked. I've used digital ocean droplet. But seems that I still don't have access to it. Somehow I cannot connect from IP1. I checked and the database is inside the mysql container. Also I can connect with the root password to mysql shell . The only thing that left is firewall may be.

Comment: Yes there are two firewall rules, machine level and cloud provider level. Both need to have 3306 enabled for this to work

Comment: Using the same firewall settings and docker-compose I managed to connect finally. Using just docker doesn't work for some reason. Seems that there are new things with the new docker that I don't understand. There was not service created with 'docker run' command and the containers couldn't connect to each other. I couldn't fix this. But good thing is that docker-compose worked right away. I was two days on this problem with 'docker run' and I'm happy that I'm out of it. Seems that with docker 17.06 there is some 'docker swarm init' and a lot  of additional things how to connect the containers

Comment: @makkasi, could you post how you try to connect to mysql container and the reponse that you get?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

for those who have not yet managed to connect even after all these tips. Consider using another port

Example:

```
ports:
      - '3308: 3306'
```

I solved my problem this way.

Answer (score 6):

I think your mysql container is listening on ipv6 (seeing your netstat result). In cause may be your docker configuration. I don't know how to resolve it, I personnally just turn off ipv6 on my docker hosts to avoid this problem.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will try that.

Comment: This worked for me. Had to disable ipv6 in my docker-compose network and then re-create the container

Answer (score 3):

You do not specify how you run your mysql container...

You need to specify which port should be "published", i.e. which port should go from "outside" to the "inside" of your mysql container.

To achieve that, you either specify a `-p` option when you do `docker run` or add it to your `docker-compose.yml`.

```
docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -p 3306:3306 -d mysql:tag
```

or `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
```

Read more about publishing ports [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish-or-expose-port--p---expose).

Comment: Hi Alex. I have edited my post. I already have 3306 port public. Thank you for your answer. According this answer I don't need to install mysql-server on the IP2 host machine and I can connect directly to IP2 host mysql docker container. But there is some configuration missing. I guess that I have to set 0.0.0.0 inside the mysql container. Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your `my.cnf` and add `bind_address=0.0.0.0`

That is working for me.
[mysql configuration doc:bind_address](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_bind_address)

Answer (score 0):

If mysql server and client are in version 8.x try

```
--protocol=TCP
```

to mysql client parameters

Answer (score 0):

Docker port mapping is the only thing that you need to configure.

However, if you still can't assess MySQL remotely do check for firewall settings.